# Erro ao fazer o reshape de uma imagem | ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 72000 into shape (1,24000)

Tags: python, opencv

Estou tentando utilizar Python com OpenCV para depois fazer uma classificação.
Porém, na hora que vou fazer popular o objeto, tenho o seguinte erro:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 72000 into shape (1,24000)

Entendo que é um erro do tamanho do array, mas o que estou fazendo de errado na hora de criar o array?

Segue o código completo:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os    

MIN_CONTOUR_AREA = 100    
RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH = 200
RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 120

def main():

    npaFlattenedImages =  np.empty((0, RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH * RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))        
    intValidChars = [0,1,2,3]    

    for npaContour in intValidChars:

        name = "characters/MANDATOR-42-"+str(npaContour)+".png";
        print(name)            
        imgTrainingNumbers = cv2.imread(name)                
        imgROIResized = cv2.resize(imgTrainingNumbers, (RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH, RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))             
        x,y,z = imgTrainingNumbers.shape        
        print("Shape: " + str(x) +"|"+  str(y) + "|" + str(z)) 

        if(imgTrainingNumbers is None):
            print("Not Found")      

        cv2.imshow("Imagem", imgROIResized)    
        intChar = cv2.waitKey(0)            
        intClassifications = []            
        intClassifications.append(int(chr(intChar)))    
        npaFlattenedImage = imgROIResized.reshape((1,RESIZED_IMAGE_WIDTH * RESIZED_IMAGE_HEIGHT))
        npaFlattenedImages = np.append(npaFlattenedImages, npaFlattenedImage, 0)   

    # end for    

    fltClassifications = np.array(intClassifications, np.float32)                  
    npaClassifications = fltClassifications.reshape((fltClassifications.size, 1))       
    print ("training complete")    
    np.savetxt("classifications__.txt", npaClassifications)           
    np.savetxt("flattened_images__.txt", npaFlattenedImages)              
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()    

    return

###################################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
# end if
```

Comment: Reproduza a mensagem inteira do erro, assim fica mais facil tentar ajudar. Detalhe: vc esta misturando [camelCase](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) com [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), a convenção em pyhthon é lower_snake_case. :-)

Answer (score 2):

O array da sua imagem possui 72000 posições e você quer transformar ela num array 200x120, que totaliza 24000 posições. Mas por que 72000 posições, sendo que sua imagem é 200x120?

Se sua imagem possui 200x120 pixels, você não pode esquecer que ainda possui, para cada pixel, 3 canais de cores, B (azul), G (verde) e R (vermelho). Cada pixel é formado por 3 posições na sua array. Logo, seu array tem que ter os 200x120 e ainda mais uma dimensão de 3, que são os canais de cores, ou seja: 200x120x3.

Quando você usa o 'cv2.imread()' você obtém um retorno com as seguintes dimensões: altura (no caso, 200), largura (no caso, 120), canais (no caso, 3).

Então, quando estiver trabalhando com imagens coloridas, não se esqueça dos canais de cores. Caso quiser usar uma imagem em escala de cinza, que só ocupa um canal de cor, você tem que convertê-la antes. Para tanto, você pode usar:

```
imagem_cinza = cv2.cvtColor(image_colorida, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

E assim você terá uma imagem de dimensões 200x120x1.

Posto isso que eu disse, é só adequar seu código para trabalhar com as imagens considerando os canais de cores.

Comment: cara valeu, era o problema do canal mesmo, usei o imagem_cinza = cv2.cvtColor(image_colorida, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) e funcionou

valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Marca o V da resposta para indicar que foi resolvida para ajudar os que vierem aqui com o mesmo problema que você futuramente.